# Rollup function in SAS

Tags: sas, proc-sql, rollup, proc-report

I would like to add summary record after each group of records connected with specific shop. So, I have this:

```
Shop_id Trans_id Count  
      1        1    10   
      1        2    23  
      1        3    12  
      2        1     8  
      2        2    15
```

And want to have this:

```
Shop_id Trans_id Count  
      1        1    10  
      1        2    23  
      1        3    12  
      .        .    45  
      2        1     8  
      2        2    15  
      .        .    23
```

I have done this using PROC SQL but I would like to do this using PROC REPORT as I have read that PROC REPORT should handle such cases.

Comment: Are you looking to create an output data set with the summary record or just a printout? If you just need a printout use `PROC PRINT` with a `BY` statement for `Shop_id` and a `SUM` statement for `Count`.

Comment: Output data set with the summary record.

Comment: It's not a good idea to store totals in your main data set unless you're using it to report later on, and it's still generally easier to use PROC REPORT/PRINT. That being said, if you want the totals, PROC MEANS is the easiest method, use a CLASS statement and it will add in subtotals and totals automatically.

Comment: I know but this is a requirement from a client :) A the end, I have to have a report with the main dataset including additional summary records.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
data have;
input shop_id Trans_id Count;
cards; 
      1        1    10   
      1        2    23  
      1        3    12  
      2        1     8  
      2        2    15  
;
proc report data=have out=want(drop=_:);
define shop_id/group;
define trans_id/order;
define count/sum;
break after shop_id/summarize;
compute after shop_id;
  if _break_='shop_id' then shop_id='';
endcomp;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you Shenglin. We are almost there :) One thing, I want to have shop_id and trans_id in every row (above we get only distinct values and dots for the rest records).

Comment: I have tried this with some additional columns which I just want to show (no aggregations at all) and didn't work like here. Could you advise me how to just add for instance 2 additional columns with some data (for instance orderdate and person_id column)?